# JBoss Fuse vs. standard Maven dependency

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse

I'm just learning OSGi, JBoss Fuse (6.1) and Karaf. How can I use a standard (not bundle) Maven dependencies without changing them?

I have a simple Maven bundle project. It depends on some third party libraries. It uses them via its blueprint.xml . I understand if the manifest.mf marks packages in the Import-Package entry then there have to be installed bundle with Export-Package in its manifest.mf. In my case if I install these standard Maven projects they won't export the required packages. So I've got the "Unresolved constraint in bundle" error message during the installation. Is the Maven Bundle or Shade plugin able to solve this issue? Or if they can't which is the most elegant way to resolve the dependencies?

Somewhere I've read the Jboss Fuse is able to resolve dependencies from the Maven repository. Can I use this mechanism somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found an almost good solution: with `wrap:` namespace/prefix Fuse automatically generates a bundle during installation:

```
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:cglib/cglib/2.2.2
```

But I still have to install each dependency manually. Is there any way to automatize the installation of dependencies?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late now, but you can do that using features.

```
<features>
    <feature name="wrap_features" version="1.0">
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging/1.1.1</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.jdbi/jdbi/2.70</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.microsoft/sqljdbc4/4.2</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.springframework/spring-web/4.2.4.RELEASE</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/4.0.3.RELEASE</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.doi.ws/mssql-fragment/1.0.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.doi.ws/mssql-impl/1.0.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.doi.ws/doi-services/1.0</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

You install the features before deploying your project to the fuse server using the features command

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundle-ClassPath manifest header.
Make sure all your maven dependencies are available in the final jar file under a single directory called  'lib'.( This can be achieved using maven resources plugin that copies maven dependencies in any output directory).

Use maven-bundle-plugin and customize the bundle manifest Bundle-ClassPath attribute with its  element. Add a path to lib folder so that all the plain vanilla jars are available as a part of bundle classpath.